# Symfony: Email in test mode: Indicate in email where the mail would really be sent to

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-3.4

When I sent emails with symfony 3.4 and swiftmailer, I can set a parameter to send all emails to a defined email instead (makes sense in a development environment):

```
swiftmailer:
    delivery_address: "development.email@myProjectDomain.com"
```

Now in the email itself I can't see where it would go to if this parameter would not be set. I could have a look in the header at the `X-Swift-To` variable, but that is extremely bothersome ...

What I would like to have is a simple info as first line in the body of the mail, something like

```
This email would be sent to customer@yahoo.com in production
```

How can I achieve that? Is there some configuration of swiftmailer to do exactly that? Because when I set up the swiftmailer and sent the email, there is no way for me to know where the email will actually be sent to ...

Answer (score 0):

I created a service that handles this kind of stuff for me:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Util;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Swift_Mailer;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;

class MailService
{
    private $em;
    private $templating;
    private $mailer;
    private $env;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, EngineInterface $templating, Swift_Mailer $mailer,$env)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->env = $env;
    }

    private function doSend($subject, $to, $template, $vars = array())
    {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();

        $body = $this->templating->render($template, $vars);

        $message->setSubject($subject)
                ->setFrom("foo@bar.com")
                ->setTo($to)
                ->setBody(
                    $body,
                    "text/html"
                );

        if ($this->env != "prod") // Redirect mails in dev/staging environments
        {
            $message->setSubject("[".$this->env." ".$to."] ".$subject);
            $message->setTo("my_dev_mail@foo.com"); // hardcoded for my case, could be changed to config parameter though...
        }

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }

    public function Send($subject, $to, $template, $vars = array())
    {
        $type = gettype($to);

        switch($type)
        {
            case "string":
                $this->doSend($subject, $to, $template, $vars);
                break;
            case "array":
                foreach($to as $t)
                {
                    $this->Send($subject, $to, $template, $vars);
                }
                break;
            case "object":
                if ($to instanceof User)
                {
                    $this->Send($subject, $to->getEmail(), $template, $vars);
                } elseif (is_iterable($to))
                {
                    foreach($to as $t)
                    {
                        $this->Send($subject, $t, $template, $vars);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw \Exception("Unknown Recipient Type.");
        }
    }
}
```

I can then use `$this->get("my.mailer")->Send($subject, $recipient, $template, $templateVars);` (I use twig templates for my mails)

Mails in an environment other than `prod` are redirected and their subject-line altered to contain the original recipient and the current environment.

Note that I added some additional checks to allow `$recipient` to be a `User` entity or an array of mails / entities aswell.